TypeORM not saving entity on database - Sutck on Save/Insert - SQL Lite Expo - React Native
I'm new on React Native world, and I'm trying to store data on SQL Lite.
I have an expo React Native project, with SQL Lite and TypeORM configured (I followed the documentation).
The problem is that TypeORM is never saving data on the database.
Here is the entity that I'm trying to save:
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryColumn,
} from 'typeorm/browser';
import { User } from '../user/User';

@Entity('wallet')
export class Wallet {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  accountId: string;

  @Column()
  amount: number;


}

ID is generated by my backend service, so this is why is not a @PrimaryGeneratedColumn.
Here is the piece of code that I'm trying to use to save the data:
... some imports ....
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite/legacy';
import { DataSource, Repository } from 'typeorm/browser';
import { Wallet } from '@/data/wallet/Wallet';
....

export default function HomeScreen() 
  const network = useNetwork();

  const dataSource = new DataSource({
    database: "test_db_local",
    driver: SQLite,
    entities: [
      Wallet,
      User,
      Financial
    ],
    synchronize: true,
    type: "expo",

  })

    let walletRepo: Repository<Wallet> = null;


  const call = useCallback(async () => {
    let wallet = new Wallet();
    wallet.accountId = "b8d89f94-516a-4ff0-9dac-257f25587b81";
    wallet.name = 'Default'

    let result: Response = await network.doPost("wallets", JSON.stringify(wallet));

    if (result.status !== 201) {
      throw new Error();
    }

    let body = await result.json();

    wallet.id = body.id;


    if (!dataSource.isInitialized) {
      var source = await dataSource.initialize();
      walletRepo = await source.getRepository(Wallet);
    }

    let all = await walletRepo.createQueryBuilder("wallet").getMany();
    console.log(all)

    console.log("SAVING")
    walletRepo.save(wallet).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err));



  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {

    call().catch(err => console.log(err));

  }, [])


.... THE REST OF MY CODE ....


So, as you can see, I'm running a query to findAll before to see if there's something on the DB.This query is executed and return an empty array.
Then I run the insert method. The problem is here. It never works. It get stuck on saving and never run the "then" or the "catch".
I've tried changing it to ".insert" but there's no difference.
The data is not being saved on the local SQL Lite.
About my environment: I'm executing the App in An Android Phone (Samsung S21) through Expo App.
Do you guys have any idea of what is going on?

You can try the following:
walletRepo.save(walletRepo.create(wallet))

